# Assigning macro variable in data step

Tags: sas

Confused about setting and recalling macro variables within a data step. I have an array of "Tumor" variables, and only one of them contains the information I need. There are a series of flags (BIN) to help me know which part of the Tumor array to reference. How can I do something like the following:

```
data tumors;
   input ID $ BIN1 BIN2 Tumor1 Tumor2;
   datalines;
1001 0 0 12 00
1002 1 0 01 01
1003 0 1 00 12
;

data newdata;
  set tumors;
  if BIN1 = 1 then do; %let value = 1; end;
  if BIN2 = 1 then do; %let value = 2; end;
  if Tumor&value in ('00','01','02') then Stage=0;
run;
```

The code outputs all blanks for "Stage" because I am doing this improperly, but I am not sure where the mistake is (there should be many listed as Stage 0). Any advice? I would want it to output the following:

```
data tumors_new;
   input ID $ BIN1 BIN2 Tumor1 Tumor2 Stage;
   datalines;
1001 0 0 12 00 ""
1002 1 0 01 02 01
1003 0 1 00 12 12
;
```

Comment: There's probably a way of doing this with arrays rather than macro variables. Can you post some (fictional) sample data, and an example of what you're trying to produce from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you do not need to use macro variables. You can do all of this with data step logic:

```
data newdata;
  set olddata;
  array Tumor[2];

  if(BIN1 = 1) then value = 1;
  if(BIN2 = 2) then value = 2;
  if(value IN(1, 2) ) then do; *Prevent errors from occuring if value is missing;
       if(Tumor[value]) in ('00','01','02') then Stage=0;
  end;
run;
```

Assuming your variable names are `Tumor1, Tumor2`, we initialize an array named `Tumor` containing 2 values, which will automatically be named Tumor1 and Tumor2.

**Explanation**

The macro facility is a separate programming language from the SAS Data Step. There are only a few Data Step functions that connect the two languages. The reason why this is not working is because SAS always compiles macro language elements *first* before compiling any other code.  When programming, always assume that your macro code will be interpreted first. I simply remember it in this compiling order:

1. Macro Code
2. SAS Code

In the program above, SAS does the following order of operations:

1. Assign `1` to the macro variable `value`
2. Assign `2` to the macro variable `value`
3. Resolve the macro variable `value` to `2`
4. Compile the data step, then execute it

To bridge the gap between the Data Step and Macro Language, you need to use one of two functions:

`call symput('macro variable name', variable or constant)`

`call symputx('macro variable name', scope <'G' or 'L'> )`

`symput` (standing for **S**ymbol **P**ut) will read in the value of a data step variable into a macro variable, but **only** for that record. This is the tricky part. Because the Data Step naturally loops, it will constantly overwrite the value of your macro variable until the end of file marker. For this reason, it is very common to find `call symput` routines embedded in conditionals.

With `symput`, you are unable to use that macro variable directly within the Data Step. It only is usable after the data step completes. For example, you cannot use this logic:

```
data foo;
    set bar;
    call symput('macvar', var);
    if(&macvar = 1) then put 'Woo!';
run;
```

This will produce an error

`ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, a missing value, INPUT, PUT.`

`WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference MACVAR not resolved.`

This is because `macvar` is not given a value until the end of the data step, causing an error in the `if` statement (and, because of the error, `symput` never runs, so `macvar` is never created). To SAS, the `if` statement above looks like:

`if( = 1);`

You can confirm this by typing in that code and finding that `Error 22-322` occurs again.

Comment: wow thanks for the very detailed info, this definitely clears it up for me.

Comment: also, one Stu to another, that doesn't happen often haha